# Is it a good idea to use scrollable Component as a custom slider?

Tags: codenameone

A Codename One Container can be scrollable when its size is constrained.

Since this works well with nested containers and brings animation for free I am tempted to create a container-derived class that is supposed to be a custom slider component.

Is it really a good idea to do this or would it be rather advisable to create a component-derived class from scratch?

To explain it in more detail:

If there are several containers with BoxLayout.X_AXIS and scrollableX = true in a container with BoxLayout.Y_AXIS and scrollableY = true, that works quite nicely. One can touch the X_AXIS-Container and swipe in the Y_AXIS. It just works in each axis. And once the drag motion reaches a certain threshold it lock to that direction, which is nice, too.

If there are, on the other hand, several OnOffSwich instances in a container with BoxLayout.Y_AXIS and scrollableY = true, touching a OnOffSwitch will only move the OnOffSwitch but never the Y_AXIS-container.

I think the Container-only solution works much nicer. All I have to do is derive from Container and make it seem like, for example, a OnOffSwitch (or slider or the like), right?

Added:

See this Form showing X_AXIS containers within an Y_AXIS Container - they draw like Android style "pommel switches":
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you did. Which part is the container and which part is the nested component and what's in it exactly?

Comment: The Image shows just Container instances drawing their backgrounds in a customized way - that is the idea. I'm doing this because if I went with a Component derivative I would have to implement a lot that Container just brings with itself in terms of scrolling, pointer handling and animation. Talking about pointer handling I even don't know if it was possible to implement the behavior that one can tap the "switches" and swipe either way because in the example of OnOffSwitch it doesn't work and I think it might not be possible.

Comment: Both swiping and tapping should work for on-off switch and worked in the past. I haven't tried this lately though. If you aren't adding any component then I don't understand what you get from using `Container`

Comment: What does not work with OnOffSwitch though is tapping it and swipe in the Y axis to scroll. If You try that it gets ugly.

Comment: It's a component I'd like to overhaul in the near future anyway. I looked at it and it's a bit of a problem because of all the legacy logic there but with the new round border support I think we can do something much nicer. This is especially true since the Android and iOS on-off switch are more similar now.

Comment: I was aiming to write a new one from scratch but found some issues in the course of doing so: #2122 and #2125

Comment: I can't do much about [2122](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2122) but [2125](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2125) shouldn't block you from anything as that's an old API. I suggest looking at `RoundBorder` to see how this can be implemented properly.